# redux action : pass parameter in axios request with hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on a React app with Redux (thunk).

I have a list of users in this table :

```
    function DataUsers() {
    const users = useSelector((state: any) => state.userReducer.infos);
    const now = 60;
    const history = useHistory();

    return (
        <div className="tableCardDataUsers">
            <Table className="table" bordered hover responsive>
                <thead>
                    <tr className="tableHeader">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Date de création</th>
                        <th>Numéro de téléphone</th>
                        <th>Pourcentage</th>
                        <th>Catégories</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {users.slice(0, 20).map((item: any, index: number) => (
                        <tr
                            className="redirectUser"
                            onClick={() => history.push("/Utilisateurs")}
                            key={index}
                        >
                            <td>{item.id}</td>
                            <td>
                                {item.nom} {item.prenom}
                                <br></br>Tcheker
                            </td>
                            <td>{item.email}</td>
                            <td>18/10/1998</td>
                            <td>{item.tel}</td>
                            <td>
                                <ProgressBar now={now} label={`${now}%`} />
                            </td>
                            <td className="tableCategorie">
                                <Button
                                    name="VDR"
                                    name2=""
                                    class="catButtonMini"
                                    color="orange"
                                    onclick={() => {}}
                                    type="button"
                                    data=""
                                    image=""
                                />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I want to get the id of the user onClick and then dispatch an action to display the user infos on a new page.

I made this action to get the user infos :

```
    export const getUserById = (id_user: number | string) => {
    return async (dispatch: any) => {
        dispatch(isLoading(true));
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`users/getUserById/${id_user}`);
            dispatch(isLoading(false));
            dispatch({ type: GET_USER_BY_ID, payload: res.data });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            dispatch(isLoading(false));
        }
    };
```

I'm usually using useSelector in my component to get datas like so :

```
    const user = useSelector((state: any) => state.userReducer.getUserById);
```

I'm wondering what is the best way to pass the id_user in my action when clicking on a user cell to display it on a new user page.

Thank you

Comment: when do you want to fire this action ? on component mount or whenever the id changes ?

Comment: @Shyam I will get the id when clicking on a table where there is multiple users, it gets the user id then redirects to a new page when there is the user infos, so the action is fired when the user page component is mounted

Comment: how are you getting the id which you need to pass to the `getUserById` ?  can you add that code as well .

Comment: @Shyam i edited the question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to use `useSelector` to dispatch an action . `useSelector` is to read the data from the store .

To dispatch an action in `redux` you need to use `useDispatch` . So you can change your code in your component as

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {getUserById } from 'your path
```

Now inside your component you can do

```
const UserInfo = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // get the user id , either from the store or from url params

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUserById(passyourId));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <> Your User Info component code goes here </>;
};
```

**Reference**

[useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector)

[useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch)

Comment: oh alright thank you very much. So i can make the dispatch and then use the useSelector to read the data right ?

Comment: yes you can have one state in the store as `userInfo` . once you dispatch the action update the `userInfo` in the store with the value you got from the axios request . Now in the userInfo component . you can read the value as `const userDetails = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.userInfo)` .

Comment: If the answers added value to your question please accept the answers and upvote it . And btw welcome to stackoverflow :-)

Comment: I can't upvote now since i need at least 15 reputation but i will do it when i can. And i accepted with pleasure ! thanks :)